# Why does my custom Google Map no longer function?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have built a custom google map using their Maps JavaScript API and Places API. It's worked fine for several months but now when I try to access the map, I get the "Oops something went wrong" error and receive the following message in Chrome's Console.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#invalid-key-map-error

When I click on that link it tells me that "The API key included in the script element that loads the API is not found." I log into my Google Maps Dashboard and the API key is still there.

Do these expire? Do I need to periodically create new keys?

Comment: The key doesn't expire unless you violate the terms of use (which Google would inform you of) or the credit card for the associated billing account expires (which again, I would expect Google to inform you about).  Since you still see the key in your account, that rules out deletion of the key or of your account.  Could also be a typo in the script include, but can't determine that without a [mcve].

Comment: I received no notice from Google about any violations I've might have made and when I sign in to the Google Cloud project, there are no error messages or warnings for me. I created a new project with a new API key - that doesn't work either - same error message. I'm not using OAuth as it is my understanding that it is only needed if I'm accessing user data but I'm not - this is just displaying a map with some pins on it. I have zero restrictions on the project - I don't know why it worked for about 3 months and now decides it won't work. Google changed something - I don't know what.

Comment: What about the billing account?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. It had nothing to do with either my API key or my billing account. The problem was due to where I had the &libraries=places parameter in my <script... statement.

This fails:

`<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=MY KEY IS HERE&callback=initMap"> </script>`

This works:

`<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY KEY IS HERE&libraries=places&callback=initMap" async></script>`

If I place the libraries=places parameter after the API key parameter, it works fine. But if it's placed before the API key parameter, it fails with the "The API key included in the script element that loads the API is not found." error.

I can see that I had originally malformed the <script... statement, but it used to work that way, with the libraries=places parameter before the API key parameter - ran for months, no problems - but a few days ago it started throwing this error.

I thank both of you for taking the time to answer me.